# Issue updating object properties

Tags: jquery

The `lon` and `lat` values are supposed to update with a call to the browser's geolocation service. Console.log statements reveal that geolocation is working just fine in the if/else block, but `coords.lon` and `coords.lat` are not updating. Could this be a scope issue? Thoughts?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// object to hold user coordinates
    var coords = {
      lat: 0,
      lon: 0
    };

// retrieve and set user's latitude and longitude coordinates
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function (position) {
            coords.lon = position.coords.longitude;
            coords.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        });
    } else {
        alert("Sorry, I couldn't locate you. Here's the weather in Paris, France.");
        coords.lon = 48.8566;
        coords.lat = 2.3522;
    }

// enumerate AJAX request settings & pass in coordinate settings
    var ajaxOptions = {
        crossDomain:true,
        dataType:"json",
        url:"https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?",
        data: {
            lon:coords.lon,
            lat:coords.lat
        },
        method:"GET",
        success: function (json) {
            $("#description").html(JSON.stringify(json));
            alert(coords.lat);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Ajax request failed");
        }
    };

// make AJAX request by passing in options specified in object above
    $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous. You are trying to use data to make ajax request before it has been received. Make the ajax request inside the `getCurrentPosition` callback where you know you have the data...or in the `else` when `geolocation` not available

To make it cleaner to read will wrap the ajax in a function that can be called from there

```
// default coordinates - Paris
let coords = {
  lon: 48.8566,
  lat: 2.3522
}

// retrieve and set user's latitude and longitude coordinates
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    coords.lon = position.coords.longitude;
    coords.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    // do request with user location coords
    doAjax(coords);

  });
} else {
  alert("Sorry, I couldn't locate you. Here's the weather in Paris, France.");
  // do request using default coords
  doAjax(coords);
}


function doAjax(coords) {
  // enumerate AJAX request settings & pass in coordinate settings
  var ajaxOptions = {
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?",
    data: {
      lon: coords.lon,
      lat: coords.lat
    },
    method: "GET",
    success: function(json) {
      $("#description").html(JSON.stringify(json));
      alert(coords.lat);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Ajax request failed");
    }
  };

  // make AJAX request by passing in options specified in object above
  $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}
```